# Are Airbus A320 Cabin Door Exterior & Interior Levers Linked?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems, aircraft-physics

Was looking at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rOI-4oGj7c&t=29s&ab_channel=AviaLearn) on Airbus A320 Cabin door procedures and was wondering if the exterior door lever is mechanically linked to the interior lever? It seems as if the exterior lever will open the interior lever but I am unclear on if they are 1:1 linked and always opening/closing one will open/close the other.

Video:

Comment: Interesting question! Welcome to Av.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Operating interior lever will not open exterior lever. No source besides experience, though.